# Android cordova-plugin-media MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED = 1 with http resource

Tags: android, cordova, media

I'm trying to play an audio mp3 stored in my server, so my code is:

```
var Media = new Media(
    "http://...", 
    function(success) {..}, 
    function(error) {..}, 
    function(status) {..}
);
```

but it doesn't work.

The path is correct, the file is good... but Media doesn't work... not play.

I have searched on web and I have tryed many solution but without success...

When I start to play Media goes in buffering and after 20-30 seconds it goes in error.code=1

Platform: cordova-android@9.1.0
Android Target: android-29

Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Solved... the url must be https instead of http

Bye